# Alignment not equal caused by float?

Tags: html, css

Tried to create 3 column without responsiveness. But got a strange alignment issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/z5mgqk6s/

```css
#DIV_1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 83.2px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1522.4px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 761.2px 41.6px;
    transform-origin: 761.2px 41.6px;
    background: rgb(67, 82, 85) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 83.2px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 250px 41.6px;
    transform-origin: 250px 41.6px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 511.2px;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_2*/

#DIV_3 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    float: left;
    height: 59.8px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 155.075px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 77.5375px 29.9px;
    transform-origin: 77.5375px 29.9px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px;
}/*#DIV_3*/

#SPAN_4 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: left;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal bold normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#SPAN_4*/

#BR_5, #SPAN_7 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: left;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#BR_5, #SPAN_7*/

#IMG_6 {
    bottom: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 16px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    top: -1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 7.5px 8px;
    transform-origin: 7.5px 8px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#IMG_6*/

#IMG_8 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 83px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 59px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 29.5px 41.5px;
    transform-origin: 29.5px 41.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#IMG_8*/

#DIV_9 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    float: right;
    height: 54.8px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 155.075px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 77.5375px 27.4px;
    transform-origin: 77.5375px 27.4px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px;
}/*#DIV_9*/

#SPAN_10 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 22.4px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 93.2875px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 46.6375px 11.2px;
    transform-origin: 46.6375px 11.2px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal bold normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#SPAN_10*/

#BR_11, #SPAN_13 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: right;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#BR_11, #SPAN_13*/

#IMG_12 {
    bottom: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 16px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    top: -1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 7.5px 8px;
    transform-origin: 7.5px 8px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#IMG_12*/

#DIV_14 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 250px 0px;
    transform-origin: 250px 0px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_14*/
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
 <div id="DIV_2">
  <div id="DIV_3">
    <span id="SPAN_4">KUALA LUMPUR</span><br id="BR_5" /><img src="img/search/return-depart-calendar.jpg" alt="" id="IMG_6" /> <span id="SPAN_7">10th October 2016</span>
  </div><img src="img/search/depart-return-mid-arrow.jpg" id="IMG_8" alt='' />
  <div id="DIV_9">
    <span id="SPAN_10">ALOR SETAR</span><br id="BR_11" /><img src="img/search/return-depart-calendar.jpg" alt="" id="IMG_12" /> <span id="SPAN_13">10th October 2016</span>
  </div>
  <div id="DIV_14">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why the alignment of the text is not equal? **right text of float:right element is higher than the left one**.

Comment: I see only right text in the fiddle...

Comment: @Roysh what do u mean? try to goes full screen u will see right text is higher than the left one.

Comment: I see it now.
A few questions - Why do you use `float:right;`? is it necessary? Doesn't look good.
Also, do you want the "ALOR SETAR" in one line? or two like it is right now?

Comment: @Jessie Campbell at #SPAN_10 Id you need to remove float and increase width

Comment: @JessieCampbell check my simple answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `padding: 15px 0px 0px;` on`#DIV_3`

and `padding: 10px 0px 0px;` on`#DIV_9`

this default behavior as you have two different paddings, you have to make it the same padding for both of them

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that this way, but I I think this is what you want

```
#DIV_9 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    float: right;
    height: 54.8px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 155.075px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 77.5375px 27.4px;
    transform-origin: 77.5375px 27.4px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px;
}
#SPAN_10 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 22.4px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 114.2875px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 46.6375px 11.2px;
    transform-origin: 46.6375px 11.2px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal bold normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}
#IMG_12 {
    bottom: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 16px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    top: -1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 7.5px 8px;
    transform-origin: 7.5px 8px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z5mgqk6s/1/